# Imitate letters in text falling down as if under gravity AE

Tags: after-effects, animation

I have a tricky (seems to me) task: I need to make 3 layers of text lose their shape and fall down to the bottom of the screen like a heavy mass of letters, so that in the end all the letters lay there in one heap. Here is what the text looks like from the beginning:

[image]

Is it at all possible in AE? I remember doing per character animation with text once, but it doesn't seem to be the way to go here, or am I missing something? Please tell me it's doable! :)

Answer (score 1):

If the text is random characters, you could possibly do this using a particle engine.  Assign one character per frame to a comp, then apply those frames to the particles texture... Something like [Particular from Trapcode](http://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/) would work with this.

Alternatively if it's a full page of actual text:
I reckon Newton 2 could do this..
http://www.motionboutique.com/newton/
Or Cinema 4D, but I don't think the free version that comes with AE now has the physics plugins included.